# I'm trying to create a chess game with Java, but I cannot get the pieces to drag or move

Tags: java, mouseevent, frame, chess, mouselistener

This is my code where I'm using labels and frames and mouse listener. However, I cannot get pieces to drag and drop, but rather they disappear. The rook also disappears despite not being called on or touched. The mouse listener does not work and I tried a simple set location and I don't know what else to try.

This is how I create the pieces, but copied over and over again with different name and component

```java
pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("blackrook.png"));
panels = (JPanel) board.getComponent(63);
panels.add(pieces);
```

This is the main issue. I set the new location with mouse dragged and mouse released. My code does register the position and placement of the mouse and the pieces is recorded. I do not know why the rook is disappears with the piece that I press on. It could be because it is the last component of the board.

```java
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    chessPiece = null;
    String name = getPieceName(e.getX(), e.getY());
    Component c = board.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (c instanceof JPanel) {
        return;
    }

    Point parentLocation = c.getParent().getLocation();
    xAdjustment = parentLocation.x - e.getX();
    yAdjustment = parentLocation.y - e.getY();
    chessPiece = (JLabel) c;
    actuallocation = e.getX()/75+(e.getY()/75*8);

    chessPiece.setLocation(e.getX() + xAdjustment, e.getY() + yAdjustment);
    chessPiece.setSize(chessPiece.getWidth(), chessPiece.getHeight());

    layeredPane.add(chessPiece, JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER);
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    if(chessPiece == null) return;
    pieces.setVisible(false);
    Component c =  board.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());

    if (c instanceof JLabel){
        Container parent = c.getParent();
        parent.remove(0);
        parent.add(pieces.getComponent(actuallocation));
    }
    else {
        Container parent = (Container)c;
        parent.add(pieces.getComponent(actuallocation));
    }
    pieces.setVisible(true);
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    if (pieces == null) return;
    pieces.setLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
}
```

Comment: Not directly related but still important (and this might solve several other issues you might face): learn about the model-view-controller pattern. Represent your board, the pieces etc. as separate classes (the model) and use the UI only to draw the current state of the board (the view). Drag and drop would then basically trigger an action calculate changes to the board and to update the model (the controller).

Comment: `pieces.setLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());` in `mouseDragged()` - `pieces` seems to be refer to the black rook label. Do you _really_ want to move it on a drag? Additionally, you're calling `pieces.setVisible(false);` in `mouseReleased()` and `pieces.setVisible(true);` at the end of the method. If there's an exception, e.g. on the cast `(Container)c` your code would never reach that last line.

Comment: [mcve] please ..